# Передача по сети структуры с указателем

Tags: c++, golang

Если я создаю структуру, в которой есть поле указатель. Указателю я присваиваю адрес на некоторую другую структуру (назову ее С) и затем благополучно отправляю по сети. Сможет ли получатель определить значения структуры С, которые я адресовал указателю полю отправленной структуры?

По идее, когда получатель будет разыменовывать этот указатель он не получит ничего хорошего.

Answer (score 4):

Вы купили в магазине книгу. Друг попросил у вас почитать эту книгу. Если вы другу отдадите только страницы с оглавлением из этой книги(ссылки на главы), друг сможет прочитать эту книгу?

Вы не можете передавать только указатель на некую структуру, "друг" не узнает содержимое, на которое указывает этот указатель, так как вы ему это не предоставили. Вы должны передавать "другу" структуру с ее содержимым. Для этого структуру необходимо [сериализовать](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/), а "друг" на другой стороне будет ее десериализовать(обратный процесс сериализации).
На текущий момент существует достаточное количество сериализаторов объектов, с которыми вы можете ознакомится самостоятельно и выбрать для себя(и для "друга") наиболее подходящий.

Comment: Ну а если Другу нужна только одна страница?.. Нельзя не отдавать книгу, а отдавать только страницу?..

Comment: "Отсканируй" страницу(создай новый объект) и пошли только ее. Можно выдрать страницу из книги, но я думаю, такая частичная сериализация книги нежелательна.

Comment: Я бы даже сказал, что передать указатель это сказать другу в каком шкафу и на какой полке книга стоит у вас дома :)